# Find the minimum capacity edge that is maximized among all paths from $s$ to $t$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Consider some weighted, directed graph $G=(V,E)$. How can we find the edge that is the maximum of all minimum values along paths from $s$ to $t$?

For example, if there are two paths from $s$ to $t$ and the first path has minimum edge $2$ and the second has minimum edge $5$, we return the path that has minimum edge $5$ since it is the path with a minimum-capacity edge maximized. Similarly, if there are three paths from $s$ to $t$ with minimum edge weights $2,3,4$, respectively, we'd return the path that had minimum edge $4$.

I'm trying to solve the problem as quickly as possible. I was considering using DFS to solve the problem, always starting at $s$ and trying every path to $t$, always keeping the minimum edge in memory, but I'm not sure if this is 1. fast and 2. practical.

In general, I'm just looking for an algorithm that can solve this problem as quickly as possible.

Comment: Their are some subtleties to this. The first step is to find all the paths from $s$ to $t$, which could be infinite in number, if you graph has loops. So you would probably restrict paths that do not circle around. One you have that, it seems to me that this is a  relatively straight forward search.

Comment: See the respective [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem).